# Create array from URL string for each segment of URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I need to create and array from a url string with an unknown number of /segments/.

```
str = "/about/history/today/";
```

The desired array would look like this

```
array = ["/about/history/today/", "/about/history/", "/about/"];
```

My best guess is to split the string into an array just to get the count. Then push the string to a new array, subtract the last segment, push, repeat. Unfortunately, I can't really figure out the regex to slice off the last segment. And creating an array just to get a count only to create a whole new array seems silly.

---

Update I think I figured it out

```
var str = "/about/history/today/";
var array = str.split("/");

array.pop();
array.shift();
array.reverse();

var finalArray = [str];

_.forEach(array, function(value) {  
     str = str.replace(value + "/","");   
     finalArray.push(str);  
 });
```

Comment: so... based on your "best guess" - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, I think I just figured it out, using the array from the split I was able to replace the last segment from the string and push to a new array.

Comment: regex to match last segment: `\/\w+\/$` but it matches the first backslash too. Probably you should use regex without first backslash, and add the leading backslash by pushing into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice solution with the `reduce` function:

```js
var t = "/about/history/today/".split("/").reduce(function(a, b) { 
  if (b != '' && a) { 
    a.push(b);
  } 
  return a 
}, []).reduce(function(a, b, index, ar) {
  a.push("/" + ar.slice(0, ar.length-index).join("/") + "/");
  return a;
  }, []);

console.log(t)
```

Comment: This is really interesting and now I'm learning about `.reduce` and `.map`. Give me some time to wrap my head around this ... thanks!

Comment: You can come back in the future and vote it when you have enough reputation for that (minimum of 15 required)

Comment: And the gamification begins, haha, must get to 15! :)

Comment: Answer some question/Ask good ones :) I'm sure you will get there!